# Finding conditions on unspecified CDF

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Let $F(\theta)$ be an arbitrary, strictly increasing and twice differentiable CDF that is defined on the interval $[0, \overline{\theta}]$, where $\overline{\theta}$ may be infinite. Moreover, let $\mathbb{E}(\theta) = 1$.

Let $N \geq 2$ be a natural number, and $\delta \in (0,1)$ real.

I am looking for criteria on $F$ that guarantee a solution $k$ for

$(N-1)[1-\delta+\delta F(N k)] - N k \delta F'(N k) =0$, where $k$ can be any real positive number not larger than $\overline{\theta}$.

So far, I just have the following result. It is clear that the left term, $(N-1)[1-\delta+\delta F(N k)]$, is strictly increasing in $k$ and bounded above by $N-1$. Hence, if the probability mass is sufficiencly "concentrated" in some interval (implying that $f(.)$ is large in that interval), a solution $k$ must exist by continuity of $f$ and $F$.

However, it would be nice to have some sharper conditions on $F$ that guarantee a solution. Ideally, I'd wish to have a result that gives an upper bound on $F$'s variance, or similar.

I would greatly appreciate any input or ideas that might lead to a better understanding. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible criterion. Suppose $\lim_{z\rightarrow0} z F'(z) =: \omega < \frac{(N-1)(1-\delta)}{\delta}$. Then, for $k=0$,
$g(k) := (N-1)[1-\delta+\delta F(Nk)] - N k \delta F'(Nk) = (N-1)(1-\delta) -\delta \omega > 0$.

Hence, by continuity of $F$ and $f$, a sufficient condition for a solution $k^*$ to $g(k) = 0$ is that some $\hat{k}$ exists that satisfies $g(\hat{k}) < 0$.

Hence, let $k = \frac{\alpha}{N}$. Then $g(k) = g(\frac{\alpha}{N}) = (N-1)[1-\delta + \delta F(\alpha)] - \alpha \delta F'(\alpha) \leq N-1 - \alpha \delta F'(\alpha).$

Now $N-1 - \alpha \delta F'(\alpha) < 0$ holds if and only if $\alpha F'(\alpha) > \frac{N-1}{\delta}$.

Thus, a sufficient criterion for a solution is the existence of some value $\alpha > 0$ such that $\alpha F'(\alpha)$ is "sufficiently large" (larger than $\frac{N-1}{\delta}$).

E.g., for $\alpha = 1$, $F'(1) >  \frac{N-1}{\delta}$ guarantees a solution $k^*$ to the equation. In other words, if $F$'s density at its mean value is sufficiently large, a solution $k^*$ must exist.

However, $\alpha F'(\alpha) > \frac{N-1}{\delta}$ is by no means a necessary condition for $k^*$ to exist. If anybody has an idea to obtain sharper bounds, I'd be more than grateful.